# What is the best way to format Django urls for two parameters, either of which are optional?

Tags: django

I'm designing a gallery application for viewing vehicle pictures and there are two parameters:

1. Manufacturer
2. Vehicle type

Right now you can view either, but not both.  Urls go like so:

1. /manufacturer/#
2. /type/#

Where # is an ID number.  How/can I format my URLs so it can accept both?  My current solution is to do: /both/#/# but this requires some retooling since the application doesn't know when you want to filter by both.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in a situation where both are optional, perhaps your best bet is to handle it through GET parameters.

Comment: Do you mean your URLs would look like `http://example.com/view?manufacturer=foo` and `http://example.com/view?type=bar&manufacturer=baz`? I thought that such GET parameters were deemed by the django community to be ugly and best avoided.

Comment: Yes, they should be avoided when possible. However, GET parameters exist for a reason, and in some situations, at least in my opinion, it's ok to use them if it logically makes sense.

Comment: How else would I achieve this without resorting to very rigid URLs, where both parameters have to be specified?  It seems silly to conform to a URL standard that makes your application harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that scheme will work for you:

views.py:

```
def filtered_view (request, manufacturer_id=None, type_id=None):
    ...
```

urls.py:

```
    ...
    url(r'^manufacturer/(?P<manufacturer_id>[0-9]+)/((?P<type_id>[0-9])/)?$', filtered_view),
    url(r'^type/(?P<type_id>[0-9]+)/((?P<manufacturer_id>[0-9])/)?$', filtered_view),
    ...
```

And depending on user’s way through the site, urls will be `/manufacturer/123/`, `/manufacturer/123/456/` or `/type/456/`, `/type/456/123/` (where `123` is a manufacturer id, and `456` is vehicle type id.)